# Currency signs in valueBox shinydashboard/shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I created a shiny-app that displays values in a valueBox. The values are supposed to be displayed with the respective currency ($ or € or £), however, only the $-sign is displayed.

An MWE looks like this:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "MWE"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      valueBox(value = paste0(sprintf("%.2f", 123.14), "$"), 
               subtitle = "This works good:", 
               color = "green"),
      valueBox(value = paste0(sprintf("%.2f", 123.14), "€"), 
               subtitle = "This does not work:", 
               color = "red")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It works for me (Ubuntu with `en_US.UTF-8` as locale, Firefox with `unicode` as text encoding).

Comment: Argh, I have a Windows machine... But @Victorp's answer produced the right result!

Comment: Yes, there is fortunately an easy workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you could use the HTML code for € (`&#8364;` or even `&euro;`) like below. And you can also use [FontAwesome icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) :

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "MWE"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      valueBox(value = paste0(sprintf("%.2f", 123.14), "$"), icon = icon("dollar"),
               subtitle = "This works good:", 
               color = "green"),
      valueBox(value = HTML(paste0(sprintf("%.2f", 123.14), "&#8364;")), icon = icon("euro"),
               subtitle = "This does not work:", 
               color = "red")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```